# Adding a customized border to an image to give a realistic effect

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have an image as shown below:

[image]

To this image, I want to add a border at the bottom so that it can give a silhouette like effect. The final image should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to add that kind of border thing. I tried to select the bottom most portion and black out the pixels but that looks very unrealistic. It looks like an overlay of black color has been pushed

Comment: my suggestion is to maybe find a math formula which can be plotted and give that kind of hill like representation, then, for each x you get a y number and you draw everything below. for example for y = 5(the real y will be rows-y), draw black for y=5,4,3,2,1,0 and do this for all x

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example showing how to do that?

Comment: @Deepak Try `cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 0, 80, 0, 0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet provided by Zindarod would work perfectly.

However if you want to create your own border you can use the following:

I created an array of black pixels having the same width of the reference image. The height can be modified as per desire.

```
height, width, _ = img.shape
modified_height = 40
black = np.zeros((modified_height, width, 3), np.uint8)
```

[image]

You can modify the color you want using: `black[:] = (0, 0, 255)`. *(Fill it with any value of your choice to see changes).*

Now append this to your image using `numpy.vstack()`:

```
fin = np.vstack((img, black))
```

***Result:***

[image]

To make any changes just modify the upper code segment.

Comment: I think he asked to add something that can give a natural feel. Though the rectangular strip is perfect for this image but I think that's not a good solution for every such example

Comment: @Nain Yes you are right. I would like to reiterate that you can append your own design having a certain height instead of the plain black strip.